# recorded video saved to active storage before creating message, how can I attach it to message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video.js

I'm using video js record plugin to record video from the browser and then save this video blob to active storage using this method,

```
def upload_blob
  blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_after_upload!(
    io: params[:blob],
    filename: params[:blob].original_filename,
   content_type: params[:blob].content_type
  )

  render json: {url: url_for(blob)}
end
```

the uploading of the video happens when the user stop the recording and before creating a message using this js code

```
function upload(blob) {
        var serverUrl = '/uploader/blob';
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('blob', blob, blob.name);
        console.log('upload recording ' + blob.name + ' to ' + serverUrl);
        // start upload
        fetch(serverUrl, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        }).then(
            success => console.log('upload recording complete.')
        ).catch(
            error => console.error('an upload error occurred!')
        );
    }
```

the message controller code is like the following,

```
def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)
@message.video.attach(message_params[:video])
@message.video.attach(params[:signed_blob_id])
respond_to do |format|
  if @message.save
    format.html { redirect_to @message, notice: 'Message was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @message }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

what should I do to attach the uploaded video to message entry in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding a heddin field inside the form view, and after the video finish uploading, I assign the path of the created blob to that hidden field.

then in the controller, you use File.open to attach the video to the message

```
@message = Message.new(message_params)
@message.video.attach(io: File.open(message_params[:video_url]), filename: "#{message_params[:title]}.webm", content_type: "video/webm")
```

I hope this will help someone